# GridDB IoT Application - Real-time data storage and retrieval challenges, need guidance

Tags: iot, real-time-data, griddb

I'm currently developing an IoT application that relies on GridDB for managing real-time data, but I'm facing specific challenges when it comes to efficient data storage and retrieval. Here's a detailed description of the problem:

- My IoT application continuously collects real-time data from various sensors, devices, and sources.
- Storing and retrieving this high-velocity data efficiently is crucial for the real-time nature of the application.
- However, I'm encountering latency and performance issues when using GridDB.

GridDB version: GridDB version 5.2

**What I've Tried:**

- I've set up a GridDB container to store the incoming data.
- I've reviewed the official GridDB documentation, including the section on performance tuning.
- I've experimented with various data indexing strategies within the GridDB container.

**Specific Challenges:**

- High data ingestion rate: I'm looking for ways to optimize the ingestion of large volumes of data coming in real-time.
- Real-time data retrieval: I need to efficiently retrieve data for real-time processing without causing performance bottlenecks.